# Solargraph not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code

I have the following error in my VS Code:

```
[Error - 3:51:12 PM] Starting client failed
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem solargraph (>= 0.a) with executable solargraph (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/local/bin/solargraph:23:in `<main>'
```

I currently use `rbenv` and have as global and only Ruby version 2.6.3
What seems to be the problem here? why do I see a `ruby/2.6.0/` above if the version is 2.6.3?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm having a similar problem - were you able to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: nope, nothing :(

Answer (score 15):

If all else fails, you can try setting `solargraph.commandPath` to the executable's absolute path. Running `which solargraph` should give you the path to use.

Comment: Where/how do you set it? some context be great

Comment: `solargraph.commandPath` is a configuration option in VS Code. On Mac, it's in the menu under Code -> Preferences -> Settings.

Comment: @castwide why don't you update your answer with this information?

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution you should gem install solargraph. If not work and get this error

`ERROR:  Loading command: install (ArgumentError)
         unknown encoding name - CP720
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
        undefined method "invoke_with_build_args" for nil:NilClass`

Try to execute by administrator in CMD

`chcp 1252`

Then try to install gem again

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Try executing
`solargraph -v`
from the VS Code terminal.

 If that gives an error try
`gem install bundler:1.17.3`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting errors with every keystroke similar to:

```
[Error - 6:08:49 PM] Request textDocument/completion failed.
  Message: [ArgumentError] wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
  Code: -32603
```

I'm using VSCodium, I changed a configuration in order to install "official" extensions. I re-installed all extensions, including Solargraph, that's when this started happening.
In the end, restarting editor via `Developer: Reload Window` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install benchmark which it seems is a dependency:

`gem install benchmark`